# How to configure Maven in a multimodular Java EE Project?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, websphere, ear, pom.xml

In my project there will be two separate ears generated with different modules.

My problem is to find out how I can bind the libraries of Websphere, actually how I can work with Websphere in a maven project.
Second problem is to find out how the poms look like.

EAR1 --> Modul A, Modul B, Modul C

EAR2 --> Modul A, Modul D, Modul E

Modul A --> EJB Modul

Modul B --> WEB Modul

Modul C --> EJB Modul

Modul D --> EJB Modul

Modul E --> EJB Modul

Application Server --> Websphere 8

Used Technologies: MyFaces, OpenJPA

Can I use for the EAR project something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <modules>
                <webmodule>
                    ../ModulB
                </webmodule>
                <ejbmodule>
                    ../ModulA
                </ejbmodule>
                <ejbmodule>
                    ../ModulC
                </ejbmodule>
            </modules>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Do you mean with "I can bind the libraries of Websphere" that you want to deploy the generated files to the server?

Comment: @reporter I want to handle container-specific tasks: EJB stubs generation, bindings generation, application deployment. I don't know what i all need. But to be able to start the implementation without thinking any problems with deployment on Websphere..

Comment: @reporter I found something [here](http://itfootslogger.blogspot.de/2010/10/maven-rad-and-websphere-how-to-generate.html). What do you think about that?